# Not able to access /tmp folder in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, namenode

I have started the name node, datanode and mr service on my local machine and all the service are running. Here is what's the result of jps command:

```
kv:~ karan.verma$ jps
4499 SecondaryNameNode
420 
4676 NodeManager
4741 JobHistoryServer
5125 Jps
4406 DataNode
4600 ResourceManager
4333 NameNode
```

And i could easy browse throw the "browse directory" of the web UI for name node. But when i try to browse the /tmp directory, it shows me the following error:

```
Permission denied: user=root, access=READ_EXECUTE, inode="/tmp":karan.verma:karan.verma:drwxrwx-w-
```

I tried to change the permissions using following command:

```
hadoop fs -chown -R karan.verma:karan.verma hdfs://localhost/
hadoop fs -chmod a+w /
```

but no luck. Please suggest what could be the issue? I executed the above commands with sudo, but still the same result. Any Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Executing the following command solved the issue for me:

```
hadoop fs -chmod -R 777 hdfs://localhost/
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are running as root and the file system to is owned by karan.verma.

you can confirm this by running

```
whoami
```

either su to karan.veram or add root to the karan.verma group